# Tweepy - Get IDs of all retweets of a tweet

Tags: python, tweepy

How can I get the IDs of all the retweets of an original tweet using `tweepy`? And also the user IDs of those who retweeted? My code so far:

```
for tweet in api.user_timeline(screen_name = "nike", count=10): 
    print("TWEET:", tweet.text) 
    for reTweet in api.retweets(tweet.id): 
        print("USER:", reTweet.user.screen_name, reTweet.user.id
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?? Can you show us an MVCE of what is not working?

Comment: Hi @johnashu, thks for your answer.I just have this but I don't know how to put it in a df: 'for tweet in api.user_timeline(screen_name = "nike", count=10):
    print("TWEET:", tweet.text)
    for reTweet in api.retweets(tweet.id):
        print("USER:", reTweet.user.screen_name, reTweet.user.id)'

Comment: You just need to indent 4 spaces :P I have added it for you

Comment: sorry! I didn't mean that.. I wasn't clear... I am trying to put the resutls in a dataframe :( ... sorry I wasn't clear enoguth!

Comment: Add that to the question and put what the desired output should look like!